# Solution Explorer Closing on Debug

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've noticed a new behavior since I updated my Visual Studio to -- I believe 15.4.2.

I like keeping my solution explorer pane pinned and open. When I start debugging, solution explorer pane is closing automatically and even after I stop debugging, it stays closed and unpinned. So I have to manually open and pin it again after each debug which is annoying.

Any idea what's causing this and how to fix it? I really don't want Visual Studio messing with my settings.

Comment: It could be due to a 3rd party, an extension? You could try to disable some of them, or reset things out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches

Comment: why dont you just get the visual studio 2017.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281339/how-to-disable-auto-hide-the-solution-explorer-visual-studio-2017

Comment: As @HansPassant pointed out, this is the solution to this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281339/how-to-disable-auto-hide-the-solution-explorer-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 0):

Please backup your SUO file and try running:

devenv /Resetsettings