# How to disable auto hide the solution explorer (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, solution-explorer

How to disable auto hide solution explorer (Visual Studio 2017)?

Every time after launching the project, the solution explorer does autohide.

How disable it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the "Help" menu of Visual Studio, you find "Manage Visual Studio Performance".

Inside this you find "Team Explorer - Home" in "Tool Windows" and if this is not set to "Use default behaviour", you will likely find the sidebar hidden both on startup and after debugging.

If you, like me, have your Solution Explorer and Team Explorer docked together, this is the behaviour you will see.

Answer (score 4):

I resolve it problem.

Solution:

Delete the following directories:

```
%userfolder%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
%userfolder%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Visual Studio
%userfolder%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio Services
%userfolder%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio
```

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (15.4.4)

P.S. `devenv /Resetsettings` does not help.

Comment: I had the same issue and this fixes the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate window layout when debugging.

Just configure tool windows (like solution explorer) how you would like them while debugging. It will be remembered the next time you start debugging.

(Typically there are many tool windows – eg. locals, call stack – that only make sense while debugging, hence the separate layout.)

If a tool window is auto hiding, click on the pin icon in its title to stop it auto hiding. Do this before exiting the debugger to include in the debugging window layout.

Comment: :)) of course I tried it.What you write is standard Visual Studio behavior. Doesn't help in my case.

Answer (score -2):

[check this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC6Xj.jpg)

click solution explorer and then right click on top of the solution explorer window and click dock.

Comment: okay. If you want to see solution explorer while executing the project, then click view on top left side of the screen and there you will find the solution explorer